# Postgres - how to avoid unnecessary comparisons inside a WHERE with a JOIN?

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, count, postgresql-9.6, query-performance

### Background

We're running this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count"
FROM "xfiler_document"
INNER JOIN "xfiler_tx" ON ("xfiler_document"."tx_id" = "xfiler_tx"."id")
WHERE (
    "xfiler_document"."added_on" <= '2015-06-28T23:59:59.999999-04:00'::timestamptz
    AND "xfiler_tx"."company_id" = 1
    AND "xfiler_document"."added_on" >= '2015-06-01T00:00:00-04:00'::timestamptz
)
```

The result of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is @ https://explain.depesz.com/s/voMo

The table is large (+30 million records), so we've run into a performance problem with a report we're running (this can be seen at the URL above; +25 second query).

### Question

It seems to me, based on the analyze results, that the performance issue here is due to the fact that Postgres is comparing the `added_on` values (step 4), and then re-checking them for some reason (step 3) for every row from the query's `added_on` time frame, rather than only checking the 18,515 rows that apparently match the `company_id` comparison in step 7.

Firstly, am I understanding / explaining the performance issue correctly?

Secondly, is there a way to solve this (other than denormalizing `company_id`)?

### Database

- Postgres 9.6.1

#### xfiler_document

```
       Column        |            Type             |                          Modifiers                           
---------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 id                  | integer                     | not null default nextval('xfiler_document_id_seq'::regclass)
 tx_id               | integer                     | not null
 doc                 | character varying(255)      | 
 added_on            | timestamp with time zone    | not null

Indexes:
    "xfiler_document_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "xfiler_document_tx_id" btree (tx_id)
    "xfiler_document_added_on" btree (added_on)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "xfiler_document_tx_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (tx_id) REFERENCES xfiler_tx(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

#### xfiler_tx

```
           Column           |           Type           |                       Modifiers                        
----------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 id                         | integer                  | not null default nextval('xfiler_tx_id_seq'::regclass)
 name                       | character varying(255)   | not null
 company_id                 | integer                  | not null

Indexes:
    "xfiler_tx_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "xfiler_tx_company_id" btree (company_id)
    "xfiler_tx_name" btree (name)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "xfiler_tx_company_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company_company(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "xfiler_document" CONSTRAINT "xfiler_document_tx_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (tx_id) REFERENCES xfiler_tx(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: I suggest you try an index on `(tx_id, added_on)`

Comment: Your description about the constraints/indexes is a bit confusing. Unless I'm reading something wrong, the query should return always a count of 1 (or 0). Yet you say that there are 18K rows involved. Please add the `CREATE TABLE` statements in the question.

Comment: The 18,515 rows in step 7 are rows of the `xfiler_tx` table, right? And the rows that it is finding by applying the `added_on` predicate are in the `xfiler_document` table. Then it matches the remaining rows from the two tables together after applying an initial filter to each of them.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I removed the errroneous `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`s

Comment: Yes, the `UNIQUE document (tx_id)` seemed fishy. I suggest you edit the q and add the `CREATE TABLE` statements, including the indexes or the output of `\d tablename`, for both tables. And the version of Postgres.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yep - that's coming up momentarily

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I added the tables and indexes

Comment: Not trying to be picky, but the create table statements that you gave don't have an `added_on` field in the `xfiler_document` table, and your query does.

Comment: @mendosi good catch - that's there now

Comment: I also added the database version (9.6.1)

Answer (score 1):

The plan entry `Recheck Cond:` indicates what conditions will be used for the recheck, should a recheck be necessary.  This will always be listed, even if no recheck is actually necessary at run time.  (You can tell this because the `Recheck Cond` shows up even if you do a regular EXPLAIN, not an EXPLAIN ANALYZE, so this is part of the planning process, not the execution process.)

In your situation, all Heap Blocks were exact, meaning no recheck was necessary.

The real explanation for the slowness is probably that the Bitmap Heap Scan needs to read a lot of data from disk in order to find the rows it needs.  You could check this by turning `track_io_timing` on and running EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS).

If that is indeed the issue, one solution would be to `CLUSTER xfiler_document ON xfiler_document_added_on` so that the data for a given date range are closer together on disk.

If your data is on a RAID, then increasing `effective_io_concurrency` could help.